# How to represent Shared member in class Diagram?

Tags: .net, vb.net, class-diagram

I'm Creating a Class Diagram and I'm guessing how to represent Shared variable in this case (if it's exists in UML) ?

Piece of code if it's helpful :

```
Private Shared m_counter As Integer

Public Sub New()
'Auto Increment ID
_checkUpID = System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(m_counter)
...
End SUb
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing it is static member. You can set m_counter attribute of your class definition to static .